# Streamlines in Boundary Layer

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose that a fluid is flowing parallel to and over a flat plate.  Obviously, a boundary layer develops in which the velocity ranges from 0 to 99% of the upstream velocity U.  Could somebody please show me how the streamlines would look in this boundary layer?  What do they typically look like in boundary layers?

Comment: The [Blasius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer) or flat-plate boundary layer has a very small velocity normal to the wall compared to the much larger velocity along the wall. As a result, the streamlines are nearly parallel to the wall. Near the leading-edge, these assumptions break down.

Comment: I should mention that the comment above refers to a laminar boundary layer.